# WP add_image_size привязка к разным постам

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Есть необходимость в WP в разных постах использовать картинки разного размера. 
в function.php я прописал необходимые мне размеры изображений.

```html
add_image_size('size1', 1600, 730);
add_image_size('size2', 670, 420);
add_image_size('size3', 450, 365);
add_image_size('size4', 190, 50);
```

Далее после создания постов, под фунекцией их создания я выполняю проверку на тип поста и привязку соответствующегго размера.

```html
add_action('init', 'create_post_type');
if (get_post_type() == "post1") {
    add_image_size('size1', 1600, 730, false);
}
if (get_post_type() == "post2") {
    add_image_size('size2', 1600, 730, false);
}
if (get_post_type() == "post2") {
    add_image_size('size3', 670, 420, false);
}
if (get_post_type() == "post2") {
    add_image_size('size4', 190, 50);
}
```

При выводе изображения на страницу использую

```html
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
```

При такой реализации WP не подгоняет изображения под заданые параметры.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `add_image_size` регистрирует новый размер миниатюр, которые будут создаваться для **всех** загружаемых изображений.

Чтобы получать изображение разного размера, указывайте название нужного размера в качестве второго параметра при вызове функции:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post, 'size3');
```

По умолчанию выводится URL изображения, имеющего размер `post-thumbnail`, его параметры (ширину и высоту) можно изменить с помощью функции `set_post_thumbnail_size`, но для всех изображений он будет одинаков.